# Taming an Ocelot in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I read other answers to my question it says to feed the Ocelot raw fish till it emits hearts and it will be tamed. Why isn't it working for me?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong. You must stand PERFECTLY still and crouched with fish in your hand with an ocelot near you. It will soon start to come close to you. This is when you can slowly look at the ocelot and tame it. Note that the hearts don't mean it's tamed. It's fur and eye's will change to a random style when it is tamed.